# How can I choose numeric output format in IJulia?

Tags: format, output, precision, julia

I want change output format for numbers (for example, printed as part of matrix). I can do it in IPython by using `%precision` magic function. How can I do it in IJulia?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is by rounding using the round method and mapping it to the matrix

```
julia> map((x) -> round(x,2), [[1.22222 3.333],[21.11 4.444444]])
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
  1.22  3.33
 21.11  4.44
```

Comment: I thought about something like this (I prefer list comprehensions to map). But it's not universal and to complicated solution to my friend who isn't programmer but mathematician. But anyway, thanks.